# Is Cache-Control:must-revalidate obliging to validate all requests, or just the stale ones?

Tags: http, caching, http-caching

I have a mess with this header, I have read that `Cache-Control:must-revalidate` oblige to validate all requests with the source before serving a cached item, but just the stale ones? or all no matter if stale or fresh? I have read both things in different places.

What is the difference with `Cache-Control:no-cache` ? Because these headers look equivalent to me.

**UPDATE 1:** I have read this from a book:

> The `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` response header **tells the cache
>   to bypass the freshness calculation mechanisms and revalidate on every
>   access**:

@Peter O. has pointed out what the RFC says. So that old book is wrong.

**UPDATE 2:** In this tutorial : http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

> `no-cache` — forces caches to submit the request to the origin server
>   for validation before releasing a cached copy, every time. This is
>   useful to assure that authentication is respected (in combination with
>   public), or to maintain rigid freshness, without sacrificing all of
>   the benefits of caching.
>
> `must-revalidate` — tells caches that they must
>   obey any freshness information you give them about a representation.
>   HTTP allows caches to serve stale representations under special
>   conditions; by specifying this header, you’re telling the cache that
>   you want it to strictly follow your rules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Section [14.9.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) of HTTP/1.1:

> When the must-revalidate directive is present in a response
>   received by 
>       a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the entry *after it becomes
>   stale* 
>       to respond to a subsequent request without first revalidating it
>   with the 
>       origin server

Section 14.8 of HTTP/1.1:

> If the response includes the "must-revalidate" cache-control
>   directive, the cache MAY use that response in replying to a
>   subsequent request. But *if the response is stale*, all caches
>   MUST first revalidate it with the origin server...

So it appears that only stale responses must be revalidated if
`must-revalidate` is received.

For `no-cache`, see section 14.9.1:

> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name [which is
>   the case
>       here], then a cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a
>   subsequent 
>       request without successful revalidation with the origin server...

Thus, `no-cache` applies both to fresh and stale responses.

EDIT:

This phrase may be relevant here (section 13.3):

> When a cache has a stale entry that it would like to use as a response
>   to a client's request, it first has to check with the origin server
>   **(or possibly an intermediate cache with a fresh response)** to see if
>   its cached entry is still usable.

So, `must-revalidate` is probably relevant when the cache has intermediate
caches, since otherwise the cache can check the intermediate cache for a
fresh response rather than check the origin server directly.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post with what I read in a book because I cannot put it on a comment, that is opposite to what you found on the RFC. What do you think?

Comment: ok the book is wrong. in the new version of that book it says what you said. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still confused. I want to cache my resource, except when the resource is updated to a newer version on my server. I've read no-cache was intended for that, but some browsers use it as no-store instead. So how would I achieve this behavior now? Can I do it using must-revalidate?