# How long should static file be cached?

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like to set browser caching for some Amazon S3 files.  I plan to use this meta data:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate
```

that's equal to one day.

Many of the examples I see look like this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```

Why only 3600 and why not use must-revalidate?

For a file that I rarely change, how long should it be cached?

What happens if I update the file and need that update to be seen immediately, but its cache doesn't expire for another 5 days?

Answer (score 2):

> Why only 3600 ?

Assumingly because the author of that particular example decided that one hour was an appropiate cache timeout for that page.

---

> Why not use must-revalidate ?

If the response does not contain information that is strictly required to follow the cache rules you set, omitting must-revalidate could in theory ensure that a few more requests are delivered through the cache. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574135/13627) for details, the most relevant part being from the HTTP spec:

> When a cache has a stale entry that it would like to use as a response
>   to a client's request, it first has to check with the origin server
>   (or possibly an intermediate cache with a fresh response) to see if
>   its cached entry is still usable.

---

> For a file that I rarely change, how long should it be cached?

Many web performance advices says to set a very far into the future cache expiration, such as a few years. This way, the client browser will only download the data once, and subsequent visits will be served from the cache. This works well for "truly static" files, such as Javascript or CSS.

On the other hand, if the data is dynamic, but does not change too often, you should set an expiration time that is reasonable based for your specific scenario. Do you need to get the newest version to the customer as soon as it's available, or is it okay to serve a stale version ? Do you know when the data change ? Etc. An hour or a day is often appropiate trade-offs between server load, client performance, and data freshness, but it depends on *your requirements*.

---

> What happens if I update the file and need that update to be seen immediately, but its cache doesn't expire for another 5 days?

Give the file a new name, or append a value to the querystring. You will of course need to update all links. This is the general approach when static resources need to change.

Also, [here is a nice overview](http://palpapers.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/) of the cache control attributes available to you.

Comment: Thanks.  gtmetrix.com will penalize you if caching isn't set a week out.  That seems like a long time.