# Problems with Last-Modified caching

Tags: c#, caching, http-headers, owin

I'm doing some close to the metal HTTP tangling with Owin. 
I have a owin middleware that outputs javascripts. It looks like this (relevant parts)

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    response.StatusCode = 200;

    if (ClientCached(context.Request, scriptBuildDate))
    {
        response.StatusCode = 304;
        response.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";
        response.Body.Close();
        response.Body = Stream.Null;

        return Task.FromResult<Object>(null);
    }

    response.Headers["Last-Modified"] = scriptBuildDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");
    return response.WriteAsync(js);
}

private bool ClientCached(IOwinRequest request, DateTime contentModified)
{
    string header = request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"];

    if (header != null)
    {
        DateTime isModifiedSince;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(header, out isModifiedSince))
        {
            return isModifiedSince >= contentModified;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It will output 200 if its not client cached and add a Last-Modified date to the header, if its client cached it will output 304 "Not modified".

The problem is that the client will not call the url again unless they are doing a hard F5 in the browser. My understanding of Last modified caching is that it should call each time to check if the content has been modified?

**Update:**

### Control: must-revalidate

- Chrome

F5 and ctrl+F5 will call server, opening site in new tab or restarting browser will call server, typing the address in same tab will not call server. `If-Modified-Since` only cleared when doing Ctrl+F5 which means it can be used to return 304 correctly when content not modified

- IE10

F5 and ctrl+F5 will call server, opening site in new tab will not call server, typing the address in same tab will not call server. `If-Modified-Since` cleared when doing Ctrl+F5 **OR when restarting browser**

### Cache-Control: no-cache and Pragma: no-cach

- Chrome

Will call server for every action `If-Modified-Since` only cleared when doing Ctrl+F5

- Will call server for every action `If-Modified-Since` cleared for both restarting browser and Ctrl+F5

**Conclusion**

Looks like `no-cache` is might better if you want to be sure it calls to check for `304` each time

Comment: Is there also a 'max-age' or 'expires' being send to the client? those could cause the 'don't call server, use client cache' behavior you are seeying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.2) (RFC2616, my emphasis):

> ## 13.2.2 Heuristic Expiration
>
> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
>   HTTP caches typically assign heuristic expiration times, employing
>   algorithms that use other header values (such as the Last-Modified
>   time) to estimate a plausible expiration time. The HTTP/1.1
>   specification does not provide specific algorithms, but does impose
>   worst-case constraints on their results. Since heuristic expiration
>   times might compromise semantic transparency, they ought to used
>   cautiously, and **we encourage origin servers to provide explicit
>   expiration times as much as possible**.

Providing a `Last-Modified` header is not equivalent to asking user agents to check for updates every time they need a resource from your server.

Ideally, you should add an `Expires` header whenever possible. However, adding the header `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` should help.

Comment: Hmm, must-revalidate seems to defeat the purpose, it will ignore the last-modified header if used

Comment: Aha, its IE 10 that behaves in that way, in Chrome it will not remove the last-modified header

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573466/is-cache-controlmust-revalidate-obliging-to-validate-all-requests-or-just-the -- It seems that for `must-revalidate` to work, the client needs to know when the resource has become stale. So perhaps `Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate` would be better.